# How to get the agg values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a sample table

```
city     member    job_status
NY       John      not_active
NY       Sam       not_active
NY       Phil      active
WDC      Martha    active
WDC      Harvey    not_active
```

How can I get a summary table like

```
city    total_members    total_not_active
NY        3                  2
WDC       2                  1
```

`select city, count(member) total_members from sample group by city`

I could use the above one, but how can get total_not_acitve?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city, COUNT(member) total_members, SUM(CASE
WHEN job_status = 'not_active' THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS not_active
FROM Member
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select city, count(member) total_members,
sum(case when job_status = 'not_active' then 1 else 0 end) as total_not_active 
from sample 
group by city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement to test whether to status is "not_active".

```sql
SELECT
  city,
  COUNT(member) AS total_members,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN job_status='not_active'
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END) AS total_not_active
FROM sample
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY city;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONDITIONAL AGGREGATION`:

```
SELECT 
    city, 
    COUNT(member) AS cn,
    SUM(
    CASE 
           WHEN job_status = 'not_active' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_not_active
FROM t
GROUP BY city
```

Check it *[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cb81999d3f55a19cda1502bd7b7284b)*